# Best approach to prevent injection in ADO.Net Datatable?

Tags: c#, ado.net, datatable, dataset

Recently, I am doing filtering in the datatable via DataView in following way:

```
        public static DataTable FilterDatatable(this DataTable dtable,string @operator, string colName, string colValue)
        {
            if (dtable != null && dtable.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                DataView dataView = dtable.DefaultView;

                if (@operator.Equals(SqlOperator.Like , StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    dataView.RowFilter = colName + " " + @operator + " '%" + colValue + "%'";
                }
                else
                {
                    dataView.RowFilter = colName + " " + @operator + " " + colValue;
                }

                return dataView.ToTable();
            }
            return dtable;
        }
```

Here, I can write a method for preventing injection(those injection I know) but indeed, I don't know the best way to prevent the injection in the datatable just like sql paramater.

Above method throws exception when I send single quote appended string as a argument in ColVal....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need protection in that instance - `DataTable.Select()` is *applying a filter to the DataRows held in-memory* within that DataTable, it's not actually connecting to/executing anything against the database.

**UPDATE**

how about creating this method to double any single instance of *single quote*

```
private string MethodName(string str)
{
    return str.Replace("'", "''");
}
```

so to use,

```
dataView.RowFilter = colName + " " + @operator + " '%" + MethodName(colValue) + "%'";
```

Comment: But when I pass single quote appended string in colValue, it throw the exception......So, I thought I m missing injection prevention somewhere....

Comment: uhmm, can you post the exception?

Comment: When I pass 'Silver(single quote appended) as argument in ColVal and Like in Operator, it throws "Syntax error: Missing operand after 'silver' operator."....

Comment: see my updated answer. maybe you can use the method to double any single instance of single quote.

Comment: Hmm...I've made a method to avoid such thing but m not sure about best approach: str= str.Replace("'","''");
                    str= str.Replace("--", "");
                    str= str.Replace("[", "[[]");
                    str= str.Replace("%", "[%]");

Answer (score 1):

If you have already prevented injection attacks while quering database, with the use of Sql parameters (the best way), there is no reason to apply injection prevention login on in memory objects.

Comment: Yeah, you are right....I m big fan of sql parameter n used to implement wherever possible....But here, in above method when I pass single quote appended string, it throws exception....